# Filtrar array cujos elementos estejam entre dois valores

Tags: javascript, lógica, filter

Uma loja virtual permite a seus visitantes filtrar produtos pelo preço. Existe um array com os preços dos produtos. Um programador já criou uma função `maisBaratosQue(valor, precos)` que retorna um array com os preços dos produtos mais baratos que o valor passado como parâmetro. Outro programador já criou uma função `maisCarosQue(valor, precos)` que retorna um array com os preços mais caros que o valor passado como parâmetro. Chegou sua vez!

Crie uma função `precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos)` que deve utilizar as funções `maisBaratosQue` e `maisCarosQue` para retornar os preços que estão entre o `valorMenor` e o `valorMaior`. Sua função deve receber então 3 parâmetros:

- `valorMenor` para representar o valor mínimo dos preços a serem listados
- `valorMaior` para representar o valor máximo dos preços a serem listados
- `precos` para representar um array com os preços dos produtos

Ela deve retornar um array com todos os preços entre `valorMenor` e `valorMaior`.

Segue o código, estou tentando mas não estou conseguindo:

```
function maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p <= valor);
}
 
function maisCarosQue(valor, precos){
   return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
}

function precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos){
   return precos.filter(p => p <= valorMenor && p >= valorMaior);
}
```

Comment: Qual erro esta aparecendo? testei aqui e as tres funcoes parecem funcionar bem

Comment: Erros:
Ao exercutar sua função passando "precosEntre(5, 10, [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])" deveria retornar o seguinte array: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. Verifique o retorno.

Comment: James, você já fez o tour? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour Sua pergunta está muito ampla e não tem bem um problema. Você provavelmente consegue resolver esse problema lendo um pouco a documentação de Map, Reduce e Filter do Javascript.

Comment: Vou procurar, sou novo em javascript.Valeu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica da sua função está errada. Você fez:

```
p <= valorMenor && p >= valorMaior
```

Supondo que `valorMenor` seja 5 e `valorMaior` seja 10, o que acontece se `p` for 8? A condição acima verifica se 8 <= 5 (não é) e se 8 >= 10 (também não é). E se pensar bem, nenhum número é ao mesmo tempo menor que 5 **e** maior que 10, então o filtro nunca encontrará nada e sempre retornará um array vazio.

Então na verdade o que você deveria verificar é se `p` está entre `valorMenor` e `valorMaior`, ou seja:

```js
function precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos) {
    // p deve estar entre valorMenor e valorMaior
    return precos.filter(p => valorMenor <= p && p <= valorMaior);
}

console.log(precosEntre(5, 10, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])); // [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

---

Se bem que o exercício "exige" que se use as funções `maisBaratosQue` e `maisCarosQue`. Sendo assim, você precisaria primeiro ver todos que são mais baratos que `valorMaior`, e depois verificar quais desses são mais caros que `valorMenor`. Assim:

```
function precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos) {
    var maisBaratos = maisBaratosQue(valorMaior, precos);
    return maisCarosQue(valorMenor, maisBaratos);
}
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu vejo os itens que são mais baratos que `valorMaior`. Destes, eu vejo os que são mais caros que `valorMenor`. O resultado será um array com todos os elementos cujos valores estão entre `valorMenor` e `valorMaior`.

Também pode ser feito de uma vez, sem criar uma variável intermediária:

```
function precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos) {
    return maisCarosQue(valorMenor, maisBaratosQue(valorMaior, precos));
}
```

Exemplo completo:

```js
function maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) {
    return precos.filter(p => p <= valor);
}
 
function maisCarosQue(valor, precos) {
    return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
}

function precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos) {
    return maisCarosQue(valorMenor, maisBaratosQue(valorMaior, precos));
}

console.log(precosEntre(5, 10, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])); // [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

---

Só lembrando que essa não é a melhor forma, pois primeiro criamos um array com os itens mais baratos, e depois criamos outro com os mais caros (já que [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) sempre retorna outro array com os resultados). A primeira opção acima, fazendo tudo de uma vez, é melhor porque não cria um array intermediário desnecessariamente (mas como era exigência do exercício usar as funções `maisCarosQue` e `maisBaratosQue`, não tem muito como fugir disso).

Comment: É exatamente isso. Se não fosse a exigencia do exercicio eu iria fazer a primeira maneira, apenas alterando a lógica que estava errada. Muito Obrigado pela atenção.